# How to use the MATLAB plot function inside a for loop

Tags: matlab, plot

I have this for loop below:

```
for Vsb = 0:1:5
    Vtn = Vto+y*(sqrt(SurfPot + Vsb) + sqrt(SurfPot));
end
```

I want to plot `Vtn` vs `Vsb` for all the values of `Vsb`. I was trying to use the plot function but it does not seem to work.

Comment: what exactly does "does not seem to work" mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Vtn variable should be an array with 6 elements.

```
Vtn=[];
for Vsb = 0:1:5
    Vtn(Vsb) = Vto+y*(sqrt(SurfPot + Vsb) + sqrt(SurfPot));
end
```

then just plot the Vtn as a function of Vsb with the following

```
figure 
plot(0:5,Vtn,'*r');
```